# What I'm missing about async/await

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I have asp.net mvc task in controller:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> ContactUpdate(ContactViewModel update)
        {
            if (update != null && this.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               await new ContactRepository(this).UpdateContactAsync(update);                
            }

            return this.Json(new FormResult(this.ModelState));
        }
```

method `UpdateContactAsync` looks like that:

```
    public async Task<int> UpdateContactAsync(ContactModel update)
    {
      Contact c = await this.Db.GetContactAsync(id);
      OtherContact oc = await this.Db.GetOtherContactAsync(id);

      // do stuff with contact and other contact

      // finally
      return await this.accessor.Db.SaveChangesAsync();

    }
```

Above code is working without any issue.

But I tried to make some adjustment to run both tasks and after run await for them and changed code to following:

```
        public async Task<int> UpdateContactAsync(ContactModel update)
        {
          var task1 = this.Db.GetContactAsync(id);
          var task2 = this.Db.GetOtherContactAsync(id);

          Contact c = await task1;
          OtherContact oc = await task2;

          // do stuff with contact and other contact

          // finally
          return await this.accessor.Db.SaveChangesAsync();

        }
```

and this code is not working as I expect: Second code never reaching second task await and save. from what I'm seeing based on DB Profiler only first task is running.

Comment: If your repository is using EntityFramework, note that accessing the same DbContext concurrently from multiple threads is not supported. But, like @Servy mentioned, you need to tell us what is not working. Otherwise we can only guess. :)

Comment: Ok, I asked question wrongly. I should rather ask what is the diference between first and second which is causing that SaveAsync is never reached in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework only allows one asynchronous request at a time per `DbContext`.